# ES6 destructuring exec function on parameter

Tags: javascript, parameters, ecmascript-6, variable-assignment, destructuring

I got following idea, but I am not quite sure, if there is any possibility, this would work.

IS-CASE:

```
handleChange({ target: { value } }) {
    const intValue = parseInt(value, 10);
    // doSomething(intValue);
}
```

SHOULD-CASE:

```
handleChange({ target: { value: parseInt(value, 10) } }) {
    // doSomething(value);
}
```

What I want: I want to parse the value-parameter to an Integer directly in the head of the function. So I can access it in the body as an Integer.

I know, that my should-state is not valid js-syntax, but I want to know, if there is any possibility, that I can achieve this.

I already know, that this is working:

```
let {length : len} = 'abc'; // len = 3
```

So I am looking for a similar behaviour:

```
let {parseInt : int} = '123'; // int = 3
```

Best regards, looking forward for suggestions,

Michael

Comment: Is it supposed to be a function definition, or a function call?

Comment: I tried to clarify myself and edited my previous question.

Comment: I think there is a missing arrow or function keyword in your code.

Comment: Okay except if this uses the method shortcut inside an object definition, mh hm.

Comment: You could look into TypeScript to avoid many type-related problems. The example with `length` only works because it is a property of the String type. But that is different for `parseInt`.

Comment: I know, but the question is, if there is another way ;)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would work, **but there is a gotcha**.

For simplicity, I have used just `{ value }` instead of `{ target: { value } }`

```
function handleChange({
  value = 10, // declare this first so you can use the variable later
  intValue = parseInt(value, 10) // intValue shouldn't be passed as argument
} = {}) {
  console.log(intValue);
}

handleChange({ value: "100" });
```

but it will give results other than what is intended when `intValue` is a property in the function param[0].

```
handleChange({ value: "100", intValue: 10 });
```

will log `100` when you actually expect it to log `10`. So I wouldn't recommend doing this, as this is leaky.

Comment: That's nice, but as you mentioned, there is a little gotcha. If I want to document my code via jsDoc, then I have to document the second parameter as well. I don't like that, as well, as having a second param